# Drawing an image along a slope in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, graphics

I'm writing a program that can draw a line between two points with filled circles. The circles:
- shouldn't overlap each other
- be as close together as possible
- and the centre of each circle should be on the line.

I've written a function to produce the circles, however I'm having trouble calculating position of each circle so that they are correctly lined up

```
void addCircles(scrPt endPt1, scrPt endPt2)
{
  float xLength, yLength, length, cSquare, slope;
  int numberOfCircles;

  // Get the x distance between the two points
  xLength = abs(endPt1.x - endPt2.x);

  // Get the y distance between the two points
  yLength = abs(endPt1.y - endPt2.y);

  // Get the length between the points
  cSquare = pow(xLength, 2) + pow(yLength, 2);
  length = sqrt(cSquare);

  // calculate the slope
  slope = (endPt2.y - endPt1.y) / (endPt2.x - endPt1.x);

  // Find how many circles fit inside the length
  numberOfCircles = round(length / (radius * 2) - 1);

  // set the position of each circle
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCircles; i++)
  {
     scrPt circPt;
     circPt.x = endPt1.x + ((radius * 2) * i);
     circPt.y = endPt1.y + (((radius * 2) * i) * slope);

     changeColor();
     drawCircle (circPt.x, circPt.y);
  }
```

This is what the above code produces:

[image: img]

I'm quite certain that the issue lies with this line, which sets the y value of the circle:

```
circPt.y = endPt1.y + (((radius * 2) * i) * slope);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to calculate the direction of the line as a [unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector):

```
float xDist = endPt2.x - endPt1.x;
float yDist = endPt2.y - endPt1.y;

float length = sqrt(xDist*xDist + yDist *yDist);
float xDir   = xDist / length;
float yDir   = yDist / length;
```

Calculate the distance from one center point to the next one, `numberOfSegments` is the number of sections and not the number of circles:

```
int numberOfSegments = (int)trunc( length / (radius * 2) );
float distCpt = numberOfSegments == 0 ? 0.0f : length / (float)numberOfSegments;
```

A center point of a circle is calculated by the adding a vector the the start point of the line. The vector pints in the direction of the line and its length is given, by the distance between 2 circles multiplied by the "index" of the circle:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfSegments; i++)
{
   float cpt_x = endPt1.x + xDir * distCpt * (float)i;
   float cpt_y = endPt1.y + yDir * distCpt * (float)i;     

   changeColor();
   drawCircle(cpt_x , cpt_y);
}
```

Note, the last circle on a line may be redrawn, by the first circle of the next line. You can change this by changing the iteration expression of the for loop - change `<=` to `<`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSegments; i++)
```

In this case at the end of the line won't be drawn any circle at all.